# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth unable to find devices (RTL8723BE)

Tags: networking, 20.04, bluetooth

So, recently I've started using Linux and got a problem with my Bluetooth device, it doesn't find any device to connect - neither it's visible for others.

I have already tried a lot of forum answers, but did not find any that work. Bluez is also not working. When I used to use Windows 8.1 my Bluetooth was working.

output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

output of `sudo lshw`:

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 00
                serial: 4c:bb:58:a1:54:73
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff

*-usb:1
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Bluetooth Radio
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@2:1.2
                      version: 2.00
                      serial: 00e04c000001
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                      configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

output of `lspci |grep Network`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

output of `service bluetooth status`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-27 20:54:53 CEST; 1h 10min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4634 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8229)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4634 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

jul 27 20:54:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
jul 27 20:54:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Starting SDP server
jul 27 20:54:53 zezima systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
jul 27 20:54:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
jul 27 20:54:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
jul 27 20:54:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
jul 27 20:58:46 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
jul 27 20:58:46 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
jul 27 20:58:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
jul 27 20:58:53 zezima bluetoothd[4634]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[    2.228723] usb 2-1.2: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   14.338918] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   16.033838] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.033873] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.033880] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.033884] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.033890] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   35.299787] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   35.299791] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   35.299800] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   85.024151] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   85.024162] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   85.024172] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1610.601974] usb 2-1.2: Product: Bluetooth Radio
```

output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thanks for your time and for your answers!